# Aggregation Framework with mongoose and arrays

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I made a question related with this, but I have a new doubt with the Aggregation Framework with mongoose. For example, I have this schema:

```
var userschema = new mongoose.Schema({

   user: String,
   pass: String,
   following: [String],
   imagen: [{ 

              title: String,
              date: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
              name: String,
              author: String,

           }],


});
```

And this is the code with the Aggregation Framework:

```
app.get('/home', middleware.yeses, function (req, res){

 usermodel.findOne({ user: req.session.user }, function (err, user){

 model.aggregate([

       {$match: { _id : '50f5c7265838530000000006' }},
       {$unwind: '$imagen'},          
       {$sort: {'imagen.date': 1}}

    ], function (err, imagenes){

        if (err) throw err;

        console.log(imagenes);

        res.send('foo');

    });
   });
  });
```

I'm trying to get in the console all the `images`, just the imagen schema like this for example:

```
{  title: 'footitle',
   name: 'foophoto.png',
   date: Tue Jan 1 2013 22:32:12 GMT+0100 (CET),
   author: 'foouser'  }
```

And get all the imagen schemas, ordered by date.

The following array at the user's schema, contains the users' `_id`s that the actual user is following. So, with `{$match: { _id : '50f5c7265838530000000006' }},`, I get only the images of the users I'm following. The problem is that, when this code is execute, I receive this `[]`, the array of images that I get is empty, so the code doesn't work, because the users that I'm following have upload photos.

When I delete this `{$match: { _id : '50f5c7265838530000000006' }}`, I get all the users, and their imagens, but I don't get only the imagen Schema, I get the whole user schema.

So, what I want, is to get all the images, of the users that I'm following, ordered by date. Is there any solution for this?

Thank's advance!

Answer (score 4):

The reason for this is that you are passing the `_id` field as a string instead of an `ObjectID`. Try this:

```
var ObjectID = require("mongodb").ObjectID;

// ...

model.aggregate([

  {$match: { _id : ObjectID('50f5c7265838530000000006') }},

  // ...
```